# How can I display an image I just created?

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page containing a form(method post).
On the submit of the button, I create an image using `imagecreatetruecolor` and `imagesetpixel`.
Then, I want to show this picture after the form.
I tried saving the image to a file using `imagepng($img, 'test.png');` and `echo '<img src="test.png">';`, but that doesn't get the new image. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Make sure that the absolute path you stored it in is correct, in contrast to the relative path you need to use in your `<img src` tag. Perhaps you could show the code, and some idea of the tree structure, covering where the image is stored and how that relates to your virtual root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying php generated image on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734867/displaying-php-generated-image-on-a-page)

Comment: @Ginso do you want to show the preview of image and upload image after that?

Comment: i just want to show the image somehow(such that i can rightclick and "copy image").
using the the absolute path changes nothing, i still get the old image until i force-reload.

Comment: If you have to use a force reload of your page, then this is a caching issue, not anything related to PHP itself

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine where your image is being created when you call `imagepng()`, then ensure your image tag has the correct path to it.

For example:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
imagepng($img, $root . '/images/test.png')
```

Your image will then be available at:

`https://example.com/images/test.png`

And you can set your image source accordingly:

```
<img src="/images/test.png">
```

Comment: the image is saved correctly, my problem is, that the resource is not updated until i force-reload the page

Comment: It's probably just a caching issue then. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728616/disable-cache-for-some-images